# Tool for running algorithm over images

Tags: algorithm, image, pixel

I know this question might be a little off topic, but I've been wanting that for years now and only did it with matlab.

Is there a tool that I can load an image from my PC, write an algorithm and run it over this image (for example, if the current pixel is red, set it to blue), and then save the result?

I was trying with my C# compiler but it lacks some libraries and I don't want to install matlab only for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is [Python](https://www.python.org/) with its  [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) Library

To install Pillow use `python3 -m pip install Pillow`

For your python code you could do something like:

```py
import Image from PIL

im = Image.open("something.png")

arr = []
for pixel in list(im.getdata()):
 #Here you get (r, g, b) and edit them, maybe save to an array

outImage = Image.fromarray(arr)
outImage.save("out.png")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, although I had to learn how to use it.